# How to insert a value from another table when a condition is satisfied?

Tags: mysql-python

I'm trying to insert an ID from one table to another where it is a foreign key. But when i try to do so, i get a syntax error saying the comparison (WHERE) has an unknown column. How do i phrase it properly?

```
    curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute("""CREATE TABLE directors
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, director_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE)
""")
curr.execute(
"""CREATE TABLE movie_list
(movie_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, movie_rank INT, director_id INT, director_ph VARCHAR(55), title VARCHAR(55), year INT, INDEX fk_dir_id (director_id), FOREIGN KEY (director_id) REFERENCES directors(id))
""")
insert_movies = []
insert_director = []
insert_title = []
for key, value in html_parsing.movies_list.items():
    insert_movies.append((key, value[0], value[1], value[2]))
    insert_director.append((value[1],))
insert_movies_query = """INSERT INTO movie_list(movie_rank, title, director_ph, year) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
insert_director_query = """INSERT IGNORE INTO directors(director_name) VALUES (%s)"""
curr.executemany(insert_movies_query, insert_movies)
curr.executemany(insert_director_query, insert_director)
```

## The next execute is where the error happens. I get an syntax error saying director_ph is an unknown column.

```
curr.execute("""INSERT INTO movie_list(director_id) SELECT id FROM directors WHERE director_ph = directors.director_name""")
curr.execute(
            """SELECT
            movie_rank, title, year, directors.director_name
            FROM movie_list LEFT JOIN directors ON movie_list.director_id = directors.id""")
df = pd.DataFrame(curr.fetchall())
df.columns = ['Title', 'Year','Director']
print(insert_director)
print(tabulate(df, headers= 'keys', tablefmt= 'psql'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned this is troubling line:

INSERT INTO movie_list(director_id) SELECT id FROM directors WHERE director_ph = directors.director_name

Translating it into more understandable format.

**INSERT INTO movie_list(director_id)** - You are telling program to create new rows and fill only director_id of them.

**SELECT id FROM directors** - By taking list of all IDs that are in directors table

**WHERE director_ph = directors.director_name** - Limiting those above strings to only those that matches... Another table?

But you did not load it! That is the issue.

I assume you're trying to append one list to another - I made you working example

UPDATE movie_list
INNER JOIN directors ON movie_list.director_ph = directors.director_name
SET movie_list.director_id = directors.id;

In here you're telling movie_list to be updated by matching data from movie_list and directors tables, which are matched by names.

**ADDING EXPLANATION**

**UPDATE movie_list** - Change something in movie_list table

**INNER JOIN directors ON movie_list.director_ph = directors.director_name** - Connect two tables (try running select * with this inner join on your records)

**SET movie_list.director_id = directors.id;** - change all director_id of movie_list table with ID of matching id from director table (in above line you basically loaded both of those tables and connected them - thanks to that we have access to both!)

It's ok to struggle - this is how we grow.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explaination was perfect, and even though i still struggle to understand the structure of the correct sentence, it makes sense to my why it wouldn't work with the syntax i've written. That's exactly what i wanted, again, thanks.

Comment: Added explanation.